# Coloring a graph with 40 vertices using only black and white

Tags: graph-theory

Consider a set of 40 houses. Each house is painted either black or white. Consider houses as vertices. Each household compares its house with the houses which are connected(adjacent) to them. In the neighborhood, if the number of houses with black color exceeds the number of white houses, depending on the color of their own house, they either keep their house black or paint it black and vice versa. This process continues. Each household compares itself with its neighbors again and again. In which step this coloring process will stop?

Comment: What have you tried?  Worked it out on a small ($\approx n=5$) problem?  What did you find?

Comment: What did you mean by "depending on the color of their own house"?  Why does it depend upon the color of their house?  For a given neighborhood, what is different if their house is white compared to black?

Comment: Is there a certain way the houses are connected to each other?

Comment: My read is that "each household changes color to that of the majority of its neighbors".

Answer (score 1):

My read is that
1. each household changes color to that of the majority of its neighbors.
2. Consider any graph.

If so, then when we take the cycle $C_{40}$ and color the vertices alternatively, then the coloring process will simply alternate and hence never end.